# How to set custom background color for selected rows in igx-grid

Tags: styling, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am using Infragistics `igxGridComponent`. I am trying to style the look of selected rows.

I have tried setting my own css classes:

```css
.selected-row {
  background-clor:red;
  color:white;
  font:bold;
}
```

However, I am not really sure how to apply them conditionally. Should I be using ngClass or there is another syntax to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [igx-grid-theme](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/sass/latest/index.html#function-igx-grid-theme) SASS function to create a custom theme:

```css
$custom-theme: igx-grid-theme(
  $row-selected-background: green,
  $row-selected-text-color: #000,
  $row-selected-hover-background: red
);
```

And then pass it to the [igx-grid](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/sass/latest/index.html#mixin-igx-grid) SASS mixin:

```css
::ng-deep {
  @include igx-grid($custom-theme);
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-selected-rows-background-color?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid-sample-selection%2Fgrid-selection.component.scss) you can find an example.